# Can the curvature of the Universe be a function of time?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, curvature

Apologies for the repetition here, but can our Universe experience (either physically or mathematically) non-constant curvature that is a function of time?

Comment: Are you asking about the curvature of the universe as a whole i.e. the [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) or are you asking whether the curvature can change in different parts of the universe e.g. as a black hole forms? The latter is obviously time dependent while the answer to the former is a bit more subtle.

Comment: What curvature of the universe? The evidence from WMAP and then from Planck indicates that the universe is flat. That there is no curvature.

Comment: @JohnDuffield Hi John, speaking hypothetically here. Assume that the universe is either of constant positive curvature or constant negative curvature.

Comment: There's a problem with that Darth. See how John Rennie referred to the FLRW metric? This _"starts with the assumption of homogeneity and isotropy of space"_. Now see the Einstein digital papers where Uncle Albert described a gravitational field as space that was [neither homogeneous nor isotropic](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol7-trans/192?highlightText=%22neither%20homogeneous%22). Curved spacetime and inhomogeneous space are the same thing. So  the FLRW assumption says there is no curvature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. Curvature (whatever measure for it you use, Riemann tensor, Ricci tensor, Ricci scalar, you name it) is a function of spacetime, and hence of time.